# Acumatica Error Invalid Column Name But Field is not used in Customization

Tags: c#, acumatica

Here is the scenario:

I have a customer that needed a slight modification to a customized package my company did. So I:

1. Made a backup of the customer's data from the SQL database.
2. Setup a new installation of Acumatica using the same revision (Build 21.211.0033)
3. Restored SQL database to the new Acumatica Site
4. Ran simple tests, and I get strange errors.

When I try to navigate to a Service Order from screen: FS3001PL,  I get the following error:

[image: Error Message - Invalid Column Names]

Here's the thing: Those fields do not exist on InventoryItem on the customer's site database where everything is running fine and I am not getting this error.

When I look at the source code of our customization, those fields ARE defined in the DAC extension. But they are never used (as far as I can tell) I tried commenting the fields out, same error. Put the fields back in, Same Error.

The wicked thing about the error, is that it does not throw anything that is catchable in the Visual Studio debugger. I am able to attach to the IIS process, and if I add an event to something like CacheAttached, my breakpoint is hit -- so I know I am in the right source for the DLL, this error does not get caught, even though I have the debugger set to break on any error. So I can't even see what the system is seeing that I am not.

Again This runs fine on the customer's site.

I don't even know how to debug this at this point.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that they are in the DAC but not the SQL database.  Used or not, once defined as a PXDB type field in the DAC, the cache tries to sync the SQL tables for all PXDB fields of the DAC with the database.  Hence, your error.  You need to either add them back to the SQL table or remove them from the DAC extension.

Check case on the field names and that it is in the right table.  There is something misaligned between your SQL and your DAC.

Comment: I tried removing them from the DAC, but it didn't help. I can add them to the DB I suppose -- but why is it working fine at the customer's site? The cache you refer to -- does that travel with the Data? Or is a local IIS thing?

Comment: The cache is the internal object where Acumatica reads the record from the SQL table and allows you to manipulate data.  It is created as a composite of the base DAC for the table and all DAC extensions that load.  Once Acumatica understands the full table definition, it syncs with the SQL database table.  When you update a field, Acumatica updates the copy in memory (the cache) and then writes the database changes during a persist.

Comment: That's interesting and good to know. But why does this show up on my local development server, and not the customer's if we are both running from the same database? It seems the cache should be the same in both if I make an exact duplicate of the data -- no?

Comment: If you don't need the fields you should remove them from DAC and database. Issue begins when you have a mismatch, it is a mistake to have fields in DAC and not in database. To answer your question why you have the error here and not there you would have to double check everything. It can be remnants of old customization in CstPublished folder, can be any type of publishing error, IIS stuck with old custom DLL in memory, customer has different DLL. In my experience this error I saw dozen of times and we always found root cause is difference like that when we double check everything.

Comment: The DAC and the data are not maintained together.  The cache that Acumatica tries to build is based on your DAC's as defined in code.  It is when these DAC's contain fields that your SQL table does not that you get the error.  You would need to publish the exact projects from their package without applying any additional code to get an exact copy of their environment.  The issue comes that your DAC as defined in your DLL in the instance bin folder contains field definitions that are not in your customer's bin folder.  If you don't need the fields, remove from DAC.  If you do, add to SQL.

Comment: I believe it is a SQL error message instead of a Acumatica Framework error message. In this case it won't be very useful to debug with Visual Studio. You can still try to insert your own first chance exception handler to gather more exceptions in debugger: https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2015/09/log-specific-exceptions-with-first.html

Comment: This has been very helpful! I managed to get past the issue (for now) by reinstalling the ERP on my dev system and reloading the database from scratch. I will check for any discrepancies between DAC and SQL.

Comment: But, is it never possible to have a field in the DAC that isn't persisted? What if I simply wanted an accumulator field for display purposes? Or is it just safe practice to always have a one for one -- DAC to Database design.

Comment: PXDBInt is a persisted integer field.  PXInt is an unbound field.  All data types that start PXDB are expected to be in the database.  The other type is not.